# Why doesn't my simple jquery UI date script setDate properly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have made a little script for a payment schedule.

On clicking a button, an input is generated. This input is a date selector input from the jquery ui framework.

On selecting the date for the first input, if another input is generated, the starting date would be the previous date, plus 1 day.

So far I have got about half of this working, but it seems my setDate option is not working as planned.

If you look at the [**following jsfiddle you can see what is and isn't working so far**](http://jsfiddle.net/rXrYy/1/).

Here is the jquery code at a glance:

```
$('#add_payment_schedule_button').live('click',function(){

    // get number of schedule date inputs already...
    var schedule_count = $('.payment_schedule_date_wrap').length;


    // get previous date if there is more than 1 date box already
    if(schedule_count > 0) 
    {
        var previous_date = $('#payment_schedules input.date:last').val();
        alert(previous_date);
    }

    // the new input var for insertion
    var payment_schedule = '<div class="payment_schedule_date_wrap"><input type="text" name="date['+schedule_count+']" class="date date_'+schedule_count+'" placeholder="..." /></div>';


    // insert the new input into the scope
    $('#payment_schedules').append(payment_schedule);


    // load the date picker...
    $('input.date_'+schedule_count).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', setDate: previous_date});


});
```

As you can see from the example, if you select the datepicker, choose a date, then add another schedule input, the alert function displays the date you just picked. But it doesn't insert it into the new datepicker.

Am I doing the selector wrong? What aren't I seeing?

And how can I go about simply adding 1 day to the previous_date var?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually 'setDate' is a datepicker method, not an option.

```
 $('input.date_'+schedule_count).datepicker({ 
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
 }).datepicker ('setDate', previous_date);
```

Should work.

Comment: oh geez. slight oversight there on my behalf. I need to learn the language. methods.. options... tricky stuff!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is so far as I can see, is that you are setting the previous_date variable inside an if statement. If a variable is in an if statement, it can only be accessed from within that statement. This should work.

It also will create a date without a val if there is no dates (Just a validation check)

```
$('#add_payment_schedule_button').live('click',function(){

    // get number of schedule date inputs already...
    var schedule_count = $('.payment_schedule_date_wrap').length;


    // get previous date if there is more than 1 date box already
var previous_date = "";
if(schedule_count > 0) 
{
    previous_date = $('#payment_schedules input.date:last').val();
    alert(previous_date);
}

// the new input var for insertion
var payment_schedule = '<div class="payment_schedule_date_wrap"><input type="text" name="date['+schedule_count+']" class="date date_'+schedule_count+'" placeholder="..." /></div>';


// insert the new input into the scope
$('#payment_schedules').append(payment_schedule);


// load the date picker...
if(previous_date == "")
{
    $('input.date_'+schedule_count).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
}
else
{
    $('input.date_'+schedule_count).val(previous_date).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
}

});
});
```

EDIT: Just fixed a duplicate variable declaration issue

EDIT: I think I just fixed it

Comment: I hoped it would - I copied your code into my jsfiddle but it still acts the same way -> http://jsfiddle.net/rXrYy/3/

Comment: Check the code now, rather than setting it in the datepicker initialization, I'm setting it before that as the textbox value (If i'm not mistaken, datepicker should use that as a basis.)

Comment: Just double-checked and that has fixed it :)

Comment: Unfortunately, you're not quite right about the need to move the variable declaration outside of the if statement - JS has an unusual feature called "hoisting" as part of its scope behaviour - see "Hoisting" in the [JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes) for more details.

Comment: @GregL I'm naturally a C# programmer so that's bled through a little. Either way I always like declaring them out of the statements :), thanks for the link +1

Comment: Thanks @jakej - I used something from your example but the cake goes to @wroniasty!